# appending code from two functions jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

to start here is a copy of my code

```
var userid ='UCLdin3PebPaIVQdIC7Lp-kg'; 
var devkey ='*****************'; 



$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.get( 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{ 
            part: 'contentDetails', 
            id: userid, 
            key: devkey}, 
            function(data){ 
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){ 
                    pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads; 
                    getVids(pid); 
                 }) 
            } 
    ); 

    function getVids(pid){ 
        $.get( 
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{ 
                part: 'snippet', 
                playlistId: pid, 
                key: devkey}, 
            function(data){ 
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){ 
                    console.log(item);
                    videoTitle = item.snippet.title; 
                    videoid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; 
                    getdur(videoid); 
                    videoimg = item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url; 
                    videodesc = item.snippet.description; 

                    var name ='<h4 class="modal-title">'+videoTitle+'</h4>'; 
                    var thumb ='<div class="ctr col-md-3 col-xs-12 ythumb"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#'+videoid+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+videoimg+'"></a></div>';
                    var desc ='<div>'+videodesc+'</div>'; 
                    var video ='<iframe src\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoid+'\"></>';



                }) 
            } 
        ); 
    } 
    function getdur(videoid){ 
        $.get( 
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", { 
                part:'contentDetails', 
                id: videoid, 
                key: devkey}, 
            function(data){ 
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){ 
                   console.log(item);
                    videodur = item.contentDetails.duration; 
                    videolength = videodur.replace("PT","").replace("H",":").replace("M",":").replace("S","");

                    var Duration ='<div id="length" class="ytime header cat_bar"><h3 class="catbg">'+videolength+'</h3></div>';


                     thumblen ='<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 pad-5"><div class="ctr col-md-12 col-xs-12 ythumb"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#'+videoid+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+videoimg+'"></a></div><div id="length" class="ytime header cat_bar"><h3 class="catbg">'+videolength+'</h3></div></div>'
                    $('#thumb-len').append(thumblen); 
                }) 
            } 
        ); 
    } 
});
```

and what I'm trying to do is get the image from var thumb and var duration and output them both in the same div

here is how i was planning it to work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wpqfm891/5/

here is what i'm currently getting 
http://beta.mdl-palissy.fr/youtube.php

it's outputting the time correctly but i'm only getting one thumbanil for all the videos
although when i append the getvids function by it's self it out puts the video's as planned (one per video)
may i also add that it's only got this problem with the thumbnails

may i also add the this will be done using bootstrap (I'll modify the codes to get the correct classes from he css) 
for info (as written in the code) the image will be in a link (the duration also would be a bonus), this link will be linked to a modal that will show when the link is clicked

is there a way i could possibly do that ?

cause at the moment it isn't really working

may i also add that I've left the console log for if you need to take a look at it

after reading through my code it seems that it's only the thumbnails that is only being given once 
[sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941272/sushanth) suggested that i use promise but i couldn't see how this would solve my problem cause i run all the code in one go but (if i under stood correctly) promise is done for running something after another part of the code has been ran

right after doing lots of recherche about this i might of just figured out how i could use this
i was thinking appending the time first then useing promise to then append the images to the div that was appended just before

i also found appendTo would that be any good for me ?

Comment: This will be a good use case for using promise or deferred objects. https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: many thank for the fast answer

i've got the demo but i'm not sure how use it in my code

Comment: Can you paste the demo here

Comment: the one that's right at the bottom of this page
https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: right after doing lots of recherche about this i might of just figured out how i could use this
i was thinking appending the time first then useing promise to then append the images to the div that was appended just before